# Error object has no attribute while running mqqt based code in Python

Tags: python

i am hitting the following error while running python code.
Error While Running Main.py

---

Intitate the device creation and registration process.

Creating the Light devices for their respective rooms.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Kiriti\Downloads\Course\Soluiton\main.py", line 21, in 
light_device_1 = Light_Device("light_1", "Kitchen")
File "C:\Users\Kiriti\Downloads\Course\Soluiton\LightDevice.py", line 24, in **init**
self.client.on_disconnect = self._on_disconnect
AttributeError: 'Light_Device' object has no attribute '_on_disconnect'

Process finished with exit code 1

---

###########################LightDevice.py - Start ####################
import json
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 1883

class Light_Device():

```
# setting up the intensity choices for Smart Light Bulb
_INTENSITY = ["LOW", "HIGH", "MEDIUM", "OFF"]

def __init__(self, device_id, room):
    # Assigning device level information for each of the devices.
    self._device_id = device_id
    self._room_type = room
    self._light_intensity = self._INTENSITY[0]
    self._device_type = "LIGHT"
    self._device_registration_flag = False
    self.client = mqtt.Client(self._device_id)
    self.client.on_connect = self._on_connect
    self.client.on_message = self._on_message
    self.client.on_disconnect = self._on_disconnect
    self.client.connect(HOST, PORT, keepalive=60)
    self.client.loop_start()
    self._register_device(self._device_id, self._room_type, self._device_type)
    self._switch_status = "OFF"

def _register_device(self, device_id, room_type, device_type):
    request = {"type": "register", "flag": "SYN", "device_id": device_id, "room_type": room_type,
               "device_type": device_type}
    topic_name = "home"
    publish.single(topic=topic_name, payload=json.dumps(request), hostname=HOST)

# Connect method to subscribe to various topics.
def _on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, result_code):
    client.subscribe(self._device_id, 0)
    client.subscribe(self._device_type, 0)
    client.subscribe(self._room_type, 0)
    client.subscribe(self._room_type + "/" + self._device_type, 0)
    client.subscribe("all", 0)

# method to process the recieved messages and publish them on relevant topics
# this method can also be used to take the action based on received commands
def _on_message(self, client, userdata, msg):
    reqString = "Light Device - " + self._device_id + " : " + str(msg.payload)
    print(reqString)
    request = json.loads(msg.payload)

    if request['type'] == 'set':
        if request['flag'] == 'switch_state':
            self._set_switch_status(request['value'])
        if request['flag'] == 'light_intensity':
            self._set_light_intensity(request['value'])

        response = {"type": "set", "status": 0, "device_id": self._device_id}
        topic_name = "home"
        publish.single(topic=topic_name, payload=json.dumps(response), hostname=HOST)

    if request['type'] == 'status':
        self.get_status()

# Getting the current switch status of devices
def _get_switch_status(self):
    return self._switch_status

# Setting the the switch of devices
def _set_switch_status(self, switch_state):
    self._switch_status = switch_state

# Getting the light intensity for the devices
def _get_light_intensity(self):
    return self._light_intensity

# Setting the light intensity for devices
def _set_light_intensity(self, light_intensity):
    self._light_intensity = light_intensity
```

###########################LightDevice.py - End ######################

Thanks,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

def _on_disconnect(self, client, userdata, flags, result_code):
pass

Add this function

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please edit your answer and add details like what the above code do and how it helps to solve the problem.